# Save a dataframe in pyspark as hivetable in csv

Tags: csv, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in `pyspark` say `df`.

I want to save the data frame as a table in hive in csv. I have done like below

```
df.write.saveAsTable("testing.test")
```

But the hive table data shows that the table is in parquet format. I want to save as a CSV table. How can we do that.

FYI I am using spark 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using spark 1.6 then you need databricks package for same.

Here is sample code:-

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("testing.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify **format** .

write.format('csv').mode(mode).options(options).saveAsTable(tableName)

ie df.write.format('csv').saveAsTable('testing.test').

https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html

Comment: Do I need to import anything

Comment: I am getting this error     py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org

Comment: which version of spark you are working ..code will work on Spark 1.4+

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6. Does the format csv option supported only for Scala